# Guard code approaches / patterns in C#

Tags: c#

I have some code that has repositories (direct access to the database) and services (business logic and access via multiple databases). E.g. we have some data that we validate in service A against data in repository B before storing in repository A. This means I have the same method .StoreThisData with the same signature on both repo A and service A. If some programmer comes along later unfamiliar and uses the method .StoreThisData on repo A without checking to see that there is a better/proper method to use on service A we could end up with unvalidated data in the database.

Thus: is there any recommended pattern / approach in C# that would allow me to 'guard'/'protect' the .StoreThisData method in repo A that would make it inaccessible to the code *apart from* in service A? Preferably throwing a compile-time error if it is attempted?

Comment: Some example code would be really ace to see.

Comment: If your service is in the same library as your repository, you could mark it as `internal`

Comment: You might want to look into CQRS architecture: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/08/22/busting-some-cqrs-myths/ https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/05/05/cqrs-with-mediatr-and-automapper/ Though compile-time data validation is not possible.

Comment: Rob: no, it specifically isn't.

Comment: You could make it internal, and use [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to make it available to the ServiceA assembly. (It's a bit of a code smell though...)

Comment: Matthew W: no, I don't like that as I'm trying to _not_ break DI

Comment: Matthew E: thanks for that, the suggestion I like best is make two interfaces, implement both on the repo, put both in DI but tell programmers to only use the 'AvailableToAll' interface.